# Find the pointwise limit then check for uniform convergence.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

$f_n(x)$ = $nx(1-x^4)^n$ for $x\in [0,1]$

$f(x)$ = $0$, clearly.

For uniform convergence:
After calculating the derivative, I found out the the maximum of $|f_n(x)|$ is at
 $x= (\frac{1}{1+4n})^{1/4}$

${\rm max }\ |f_n(x)|\rightarrow 0$.

Is that right? Im not sure about the limit of the maximum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking $x_n = n^{-1/4} \in [0,1]$, we have

$$f_n(x_n) = n n^{-1/4}(1-(n^{-1/4})^4)^n = n^{3/4}(1 - 1/n)^n,$$

and

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f_n(x)| \geqslant\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x_n) = \infty \cdot e^{-1} = \infty$$

Thus, convergence is non-uniform.

Comment: Please can you tell me about a method by which we can find such x. I know it may be found by trial and error, but can you give me some clever way?

Comment: Pointwise convergence means $|f_n(x) - f(x)|$ can be made small by taking sufficiently large $n$ with $x$ fixed. Non-uniform convergence arises when the domain allows us to find an $x_n$ for any $n$ so there is some cancelling effect keeping $|f_n(x) - f(x)|$ from getting small.  Usually this is possible if the domain includes the point $0$ or is unbounded.  I could see that if $1/x_n$ grows more slowly than $n$, then $nx_n$ tends to $\infty$.  The second factor is always bounded between $0$ and $1$ so I picked $x_n = n^{-1/4}$ because it was convenient to have a limit I recognized $> 0$.

Comment: Also,  notice that $n^{-1/4}$ is comparable to $(4n+1)^{-1/4}$ where you found the maximum to be located. I think it is just a bit easier to use my approach rather than try and find the limit of the maximum in this case.  Nevertheless, you had the correct idea.

Comment: My edit was to fix a tiny typo in the last line, replacing "in" with "is".

Comment: @RRL: Thank you very much!!!